# Find common tangents of two convex polygons

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given two convex polygons P, Q separated by a line, how can I find their common tangents?
There should be 4 total.

Geometry isn't my strong side so any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why 4? If you look at the limit, where the polygons look more like circles, there are only 2 tangents. What am I missing?

Comment: @anatolyg the two that cross in the middle

Comment: A google search finds solutions. eg: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tangents-two-convex-polygons/

Comment: Four only if the polygons are disjoint.

Comment: That is probably not going to help you, but the outer tangents are two sides of the convex hull of the two polygons, which you can find efficiently in time O(N) by Graham's walk.

https://geomalgorithms.com/polypoly2.gif

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are absolutely correct in that this can be done in O(n) time by walking along the boundaries and tilting a line that touches or passes through the polygons. Well, it can be done in different ways but essentially based on the same idea. However, I have not heard of "Graham's walk". Graham's scan to compute convex hulls, yes, but not "Graham's walk". Can you give a reference to it?

Comment: @Håkan: they are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any tangent will be generated from (at least) one point on each polygon. The tangent forms a half-space for each polygon, containing that entire polygon; different tangents are generated by requiring that each polygon be above or below the tangent line.

Whenever you have a problem involving two convex polygons, the algorithm probably involves "pick a point on each one, then iterate." This algorithm is no different.

What you do, basically, is start with a random guess, and refine. Pick a vertex on each polygon and calculate the line through the two vertices. Look at polygon A and see whether either of the two neighboring vertices is on the wrong side of the line. If one is, replace the current vertex with that vertex. Then do the same check on polygon B. Then, if you updated either vertex, repeat. Eventually the lines will converge to tangents with each vertex the extremal one in the desired direction.

Comment: It is more complex than that. In particular, there can be four solutions, are you going to restart other random searches ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The starting point doesn't determine the solution. The direction of the predicate does. e.g. the tangent which satisfies "Find a point p in A and a point q in B such that all points in A are to the left of pq and all points in B are to the right of pq" has a unique solution (modulo collinear points of course), and it is distinct from the tangent which requires all points from both A and B to be to the right of pq.

Comment: (That's what I described in my first paragraph.)